# Build failed due to deprecated Android v1 embedding even after upgrading pre 1.12 Android projects

Tags: android, flutter, build, android-manifest, deprecated

I'm trying to run a project that's posted on GitHub(https://github.com/Ronak99/FoodDelivery-App-UI) and it's built with Flutter. Initially, the code didn't run at all, but after upgrading Flutter, I got an error saying "Build failed due to use of deprecated Android v1 embedding."

I followed the solution provided on Stack Overflow to upgrade pre-1.12 Android projects by making changes to the AndroidManifest.xml file(i.e. through this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects#full-flutter-app-migration), but the error persists. I'm not sure what else I can do to fix this issue.

Can someone please help me figure out how to resolve this error and get the project running? Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln4C0.png)

I followed the solution provided on Stack Overflow to upgrade pre-1.12 Android projects by making changes to the AndroidManifest.xml file. Specifically, I added the following lines to the application tag:

```
android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
to
android:name="${FoodDelivery-App-UI-master}"

next added three lines
<meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
instead of 
<meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
```

However, the error message "Build failed due to use of deprecated Android v1 embedding" still appears when I try to build the project.

I was expecting the project to build successfully without any errors after upgrading Flutter and following the steps to upgrade pre-1.12 Android projects.